# i have been having this issues for some week now but to know avail, anytime i click flutter run i get this errors

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/localizations.dart:401:39: Error: Method not found: 'Localizations.localeOf'.
locale: locale ?? Localizations.localeOf(context),
^^^^^^^^

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 991
- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.

> Process 'command 'C:\src\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more
  log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

i need help please

Answer (score -1):

run `flutter clean`
after which you run
`flutter pub get`
and then
`flutter run`

It should fix it